# Excel Index match with multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

I have 2 worksheets, Home and Data.

Data:

```
Column A                        Column B         Col C     Col D     Col E         Col F
ABC2 121 - ABC2 121             ABC2             3456                12/12/2016    =WeekNum(E1) - SPAM
123420121601     - 2678         123420121601     1234      2678      18/12/2016    =WeekNum(E2)
628428121601     - 9862          628428121601     6284      9862      21/12/2016    =WeekNum(E3)
```

Column A contains random text and a PO number and item no, e.g. the PO of ABC123456781011 would be 123456781011 and the item number would be 2678.

I am extracting the PO number into column B.

In Column C i am getting the first four digits of the PO, this is the supplier number.

In column D i have my item number. This is also extracted from the cell in column A.

The date in column E is also extracted from the PO e.g.
`123420121601  = a date of 201216` but converted as date.

Note cell A1 contains no PO and is considered a SPAM row. i do not want/need to use it in anyway so it must be disregarded.

Next

Home:

```
Column H       Column I         Col J                Col L    

1234           2678             18/12/2016           123420121601     
6284           9862             51                   628428121601
```

I am trying to use an index match in col D that will give the PO number from my data sheet where the supplier number, item number and date match.

However, on the home sheet in column J, on the last row - a user has input a week number rather than the actual date. I still want to be able to return a PO value if either the date matches exactly or if the week number for that date matches.

Here's what i have so far but the index match is not checking my criteria properly and i am getting an incorrect result. It gives me a result from the PO of the first row on sheet data.

```
=INDEX(Data!B:B,SUMPRODUCT(IF(YEAR(Home!$J10)<2016,(Data!F:F=Home!J10),(Data!E:E=Home!J10))*(Data!C:C=Home!H10)*(Data!D:D=Home!I10)*ROW(Data!B:B)))
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: wouldnt using SUMIFS() be much easier? You could do something like 'SUMIFS([parameters where a date is provided]) + SIMIFS([parameters where a weeknum is provided])

Comment: @Bing.Wong, would you mind closing your previous posts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index Match with multiple criteria not working properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273489/index-match-with-multiple-criteria-not-working-properly)